# Don't understand the formula of absolute position encoder

Tags: nlp, transformer-model

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AD1e.png)

I can't understand this simple formula in NLP because I specialize in CV. I know what dose Xi*Wq*(Xj*Wk)T mean. But why do E and W exchange and why do Exi and Wq transpose rather than Exj and Wk in the formula.